# chi square or t-test for this case?

Tags: t-test, chi-squared-test

I have collected data on the performance of two different website versions. Both pages have been shown on randomly (but not maybe equally) to different people.

So my contingency table is as shown below, and I want to perform a statistical test to make sure the conclusions about the conversions are right.

```
   A       B
 8 000   1 000  conversions
90 000  30 000  no conversions
```

The conversion rate for A appears to be 8,8% and the conversion rate for B appears to be 3,3%

I myself did this with a chisq.test, with a hypothesis as follows: "are the differences between A and B significant". What I was trying to test was if I can trust the conversion rates that I am getting and they are not just a product of coincidence

In order to make sure that the conclusions are reliable I used the Chi-square test. However, I was told that I was supposed to use the t.test and now I am confused why.

Which test (`t.test` or `chisq.test`) would you choose and why?

Comment: Why not tell us what you think and why so someone can help you with your confusion?

Answer (score 1):

Strictly, the t test is not appropriate since there is no need to independently estimate the standard deviation.  A z test or a chisquare test are more appropriate, and both are asymptotically equivalent.

The difference would be significant by either test.  The R code to perform a textbook z test is

```
> prop.test(x = c(8000, 1000), n = c(90000, 30000), correct = F)

    2-sample test for equality of proportions without continuity correction

data:  c(8000, 1000) out of c(90000, 30000)
X-squared = 1001, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.05280187 0.05830924
sample estimates:
    prop 1     prop 2 
0.08888889 0.03333333
```

Looks like you achieved a lift in conversion of 5.5% (95% CI 5.3% - 5.8%) (assuming A is the new variant)